# Homotopy on closed interval on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: homotopy-theory

All continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are homotopic. If we have $f, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $h: [0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defines a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ with $h(t, x) = f(x) + t(g(x)-f(x))$. But what if, instead of $\mathbb{R}$, we consider functions on a closed interval of reals $[a,b]$? Does it matter where the endpoints are sent to in terms of homotopy? Are there at least two different functions in terms of homotopy? For example, if one function starts with $f(a)=b$, ends with $f(b)=a$ and the other starts with $g(a)=a$ and ends with $g(b)=b$. Can the endpoints just as well be transformed like in the case of all of
$\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: They are still homotopic. In general, if $Y\subseteq X,$ we can ask, given any function $\alpha:Y\to Z,$ and $f,g:X\to Z$ with $f_{|Y}=g_{|Y}=h,$ that there is a homotopy relative to $h,$ which is a homotopy $H$ between $f,g$ with $H(y,t)=h(y)$ for all $y\in Y, t\in[0,1].$ This is common with $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=\{0,1\}.$ These are then called homotopic paths. But that kind of restriction $(H(y,t)=h(y))$ is not what we mean in general. (I don’t know if “relative homotopy” is the correct term.)

Comment: More specifically, we’d call them “homotopic paths from $h(0)$ to $h(1).$”

Comment: do you mean h when you say alpha?

Comment: Yes, that was an editing error.

Comment: But this is only the case when $f$ and $g$ are equal when restricted to $Y$.